# Pasting images (excel Table) in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to paste excel table as picture into PPT though VBA
but the images are not in the desired shape as codded

The Require coordinates are:

```
Height 14.80
Width 23.28
Top 2.13
Left 5.3
```

and the output coordinates are like:

```
H-18.73 CM
W-23.28 CM
Horizontal-5.3 CM
Vertical-2.13
```

below is my code:

```
Range(cel.Value).Copy
newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide cel.Offset(0, -1).Value
Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(cel.Offset(0, -1).Value)
activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).Select
newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(14.80)
newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(23.28)
newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = Application.CentimetersToPoints(2.13)
newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = Application.CentimetersToPoints(5.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good workaround is to place a shape where you want it and use Debug.print to read the position in points.